# Error when Installing Ethereum: Package 'ethereum' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ethereum

I am installing Ethereum on Ubuntu 17.10 following the steps in this article:
https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f

But when executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ethereum is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ethereum' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that there is a compatibility issue with the last stable version of Ethereum and Ubuntu 17.10; and the latest **unstable** version could be installed with no issues:

```
sudo apt-get install ethereum-unstable
```

However, this means that in the next stable version of Ethereum there will be no issues.

Comment: Described here too: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/24444#issuecomment-1049675403 :(

Answer (score 6):

Have you added the Ethereum repository? If not, try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question:  sudo apt-get install ethereum did not work!

Comment: @MuhammadAltabba If you hadn't added the repository as mentioned above, installing ethereum probably wouldn't work. So it's a valid answer, though badly written.

Comment: Note that sudo apt install ethereum will not work on newer versions of ubuntu at the time of writing. You can try ethereum-unstable instead.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried common software properties
first use this command to install this

(1) sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

and then use ethereum ppa

(2) sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum

(3) sudo apt-get update

(4) sudo apt-get install ethereum

Comment: try all steps one by one

Answer (score 1):

Installing an unstable version of `ethereum` package does not seem like a good idea.

Considering that package is only about installing a bunch of binaries (geth, swarm and other ethereum tools) into your filesystem. I would suggest to download the latest stable version directly from [ethereum CDN servers](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) or compile them yourself following the instructions described at their official [github repo](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)